# Generate Strings from regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I am using regex to get some part of String. lets say i am capturing 3 group. I store these 3 groups in db. Now I want to recreate the original string from those groups. Is there a way this can be done?

For example Original String

```
longPrefix-202007_3847c820e158484dbc6ff486fc08cf6a.someSuffix
```

Regex

```
^(longPrefix-)(\d+)(_)([a-fA-F0-9]+)(.someSuffix)
```

after this there will be 3 groups,

```
group1: longPrefix-
group2: 202007
group3: _
group4: 3847c820e158484dbc6ff486fc08cf6a
group5: .someSuffix
```

i am only storing group2, and group4, because that is only changing part.

The question is that **can I generate Original string only by using group2, group4 and regex?**

Comment: Concat the values, what is the issue?

Comment: If `longPrefix-`, `_` and `.someSuffix` are constants, why don't you simply reuse the constants? Do you have any particular reason to parse the RegExp?

Comment: the somesuffix was for example only, they may also be variable. the problem with `contact the value` is that someone will have to keep append and regex logic in sync.

Comment: If the pattern of the RegExp is always the same, I would suggest you write a RegExp to parse your RegExp. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any regex java API that lets you access it in that sense.

In other words, in theory you can write software that determines that, provided the regexp matched plus the contents of group 2 and group 4, that the input must have been - input here -, but that's such a bizarre thing to want, and no java-based regexp implementation I know of gives you the API calls you'd need to write such a thing.

So either dig in and spend a few weeks writing that yourself, or just write it for this specific case: Match the regexp itself with a simple method taking in two strings and just emitting `return "longPrefix-" + in1 + "_" + in2 + ".someSuffix";`.